# Is is possible to embed Jupyter Notebook theme to the exported version?

Tags: themes, jupyter-notebook

I'm using custom code syntax theme on notebook: https://github.com/merqurio/jupyter_themes

Is it possible to embed that theme on the saved notebook so that when it is viewed from http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/ it will show chosen theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do it directly via your specific theming plugin but you can specify custom css so that nbviewer will use it:

http://www.aaronschlegel.com/display-custom-ipython-notebook-themes-in-nbviewer/

Comment: Right. I have used that procedure with external stylesheets. In case of code highlighter, there probably needs to be some javascsript files included as well, but then comes security issues... probably nbviewer will surpress js content...